# /sbin/sh:ping:not found [no such file or directory] but the file exist

Tags: solaris

How should I solve this problem,

```
/sbin/sh:ping:not found [no such file or directory]
```

but the file do really exist. When I find the file using command which it stated not found too. But files do exist and I can't use the commands! `bin -> ./usr/bin` and `sbin -> ./usr/sbin` have `softlink` and I can't think of any others reason which the files can't be find. Somebody please help :
    ( It is in Solaris 11.3 virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wish to use `ping` on Solaris but don't have the appropriate directory (`/usr/sbin`) in your path.

To add `/usr/sbin` to your path, add

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
```

to your `~/.profile` file and restart the shell session.